# Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net-remoting

In my .net 2.0 application Remote object suddenly destroyed and thrown the below exception.
"Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified."

I have IPC remoting server and which create a singleton object.

i have override the InitializeLifetimeService()  method and returns null for infinite lifetime.

server and client applications are working fine but some times we got the above exception.

serverCode:

//create and register the processheartbeat.
                BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverprovider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
                serverprovider.TypeFilterLevel = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.TypeFilterLevel.Full;
                //Hosts the Heartbeat object and registers it.
                processHeartbeatChn = new IpcServerChannel("HeartbeatChannel", "localhost:" + applicationHeartbeatPort, serverprovider);

```
            //registers the channel
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(processHeartbeatChn, false);

            //register the service
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(Heartbeat),
                appName, WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

ClientCode:

```
            string uri = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"ipc://localhost:{0}/{1}", applicationHeartbeatPort, appName);

            //get the Heartbeat object
            remoteHeartbeat = (Heartbeat)Activator.GetObject(typeof(Heartbeat), uri);
```

any hot fix is there to resolve this problem?

can any one help me an this?